# Возможна ли гибель квартиры?

Tags: выбор-слов, лексика

Недавно в одном договоре встретил словосочетание "гибель квартиры". Смысл фразы понятен, но слух почему-то режет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это юридически значимый текст, то все нормально. 
"Гибель имущества" (каковым может являться и квартира) - это терминология сложившаяся. И как иначе сказать? Утрата? Потеря? Это все не то. 
Уничтожение - получше, но предусматривает направленное действие.

Меня даже более смущает само "квартира". Точнее было бы "гибель жилища". Квартира сама по себе погибнуть не может. Только вместе с домом, в котором она находится. Поэтому формулировка "гибель квартиры" у хорошего юриста-крючкотвора может вызвать некоторые вопросы.

Но это все мелочи. По большому счету "гибель квартиры" вполне пригодно к употреблению в соответствующих контекстах.

Comment: Вот у меня эти вопросы и вызвало. Спасибо, неестественность фразы чувствовалась, но в чём именно никак не мог разобраться.